# ASPNETDB.MDF version conflict

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on a project on my home computer which has Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on it.  I saved the project to a flash drive and did some work on it in the office where Visual Web Developer 2010 is installed.

The project so far just has the login screen which uses a .net login control.  It was working on my home computer, and worked on my work computer.  But after I brought it back home and tried to run it I get an error saying:

"The database '(my flash drive path)/ASPNETDB.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 661. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported."

So apparently when I ran it on my work computer it set the database to version 661.  What can I do now so I can run it on my home computer?  What changes do I need to make to make sure I can work on this project in both places going forward?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to update SQL Server (or SQL Server Express, as appropriate) on your home computer to the [currently released version](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx).

Comment: thanks, I'll give this a shot.  I'm new to working with the aspnetdb.mdf so I didn't want to mess anything up.